# Return multiple json objects in flask

Tags: json, flask

I want to return multiple json objects

```
 def json_example():
    for container in containers:
     jsonresult =  jsonify(Product = product_name , Price = final_price,Details = quantity)
     return jsonresult
```

But this only returns one json object.I want to return multiple json objects.
this returns

```
{"Details": "1 L",
"Price": "275",
"Product": "HARPIC BATHROOM FLOOR CLEANER 1000 ml lemon}
```

Comment: From your question it's not quite clear how `containers` is structured, is it a list of dicts?

Comment: containers is just a list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
the_dict = dict()
def json_example(the_dict):
    for container in containers:
        jsonresult =  jsonify(Product = product_name , Price = final_price,Details = quantity)
        the_dict[container] = jsonresult
    return the_dict
```

Now `the_dict` should contain all json objects. You can also build a list and append to it.

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Tag' and 'Tag'  now I get this error

Comment: But where in your code? I doubt if it is related to this part!

Comment: but when i remove your code and run it i get jsonresult

Comment: Could be. but without any clue about the rest of your code this is what I can only suggest. Please try to modify your question, for me to be able to produce your results!